# I can't use trigger to update info from two tables, MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

Hello i have this problem:
I have 2 tables :

```
Create table Student(
    Num int Auto_increment,
    Name varchar(100),
    Age int,
    Gpa int default 2,
    
    primary key(Num)
);

Create table Grades(
    Num int,
    Grade_BG int default 2,
    Grade_Math int default 2,
    Grade_SUBD int default 2,
    
    Primary key (Num)
);
```

And i want to make a trigger to update the GPA with the three grades from the other table but i'm having hard time doing it.

Comment: I have no idea what a gpa is or how it would be generated from 3 grades, you might want to expand on this. You could clarify by providing sample data and expected outcome as text

Comment: Also if you have a code attempt please publish it.

Comment: Add INSERT INTO with initial data. Then add a query (INSERT? UPDATE? DELETE?) and desired final data state after needed trigger action performing (with explanations).

Comment: Gpa is average grade

Comment: @P.Salmon ``` create trigger stud_marks
after INSERT
on Grades
for each row
update Student
set Gpa = (Grades.Grade_BG+Grades.Grade_Math+Grades.Grade_SUBD)/3;

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger code :-

```
create trigger stud_marks after INSERT on Grades 
for each row 
update Student 
 set Gpa = (Grades.Grade_BG+Grades.Grade_Math+Grades.Grade_SUBD)/3;
```

The for each row means for each row inserted to grades so the grades. qualifier is unnecessary and should be replaced with NEW. 'Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Also the update needs to know which student to update so a where clause would be useful

so

```
create trigger stud_marks after INSERT on Grades 
for each row 
update Student 
 set Gpa = (new.Grade_BG+new.Grade_Math+new.Grade_SUBD)/3
 where student.num = new.num;
```

Assuming num in grades actually relates to num in student. If not then you need to create a relationship.

You may also need to create UPDATE and DELETE triggers.